# EntityFramework4.1's .Local().ToBindingList() , How to filter then?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Example Model: Customer -> Order

```
contex.Order.Load();
orderBindingSource.DataSource = context.Order.Local().ToBindingList();
```

Then, how to filter? e.g.  `context.Order.Where(m=>m.customerID > 1)`

I want to get the BindingList implementation that stays in sync with the ObservableCollection returned by the Local property.

Comment: Right... this is tricky because `.Where` produces an `IQueryable`, which since it's no longer a `DBSet`, you can't call `.Local` on it. How are you intended to use `.Local` on limited sets of your data? It can't be intended for only using on entire `DBSet`s, can it? This is still an issue on the latest EF4, as far as I can tell, and the MSDN docs are non-helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using select?

```
contex.Order.Load();
orderBindingSource.DataSource = 
   context.Order.Local().Select( m => m.customerID > 1).ToBindingList();
```

**Edit**

Not entirely sure about this, it compiles but I do not have a full environment to test it. Perhaps if you try to load in the specific data, and then you can access it in local for the binding list. Like this:

```
context.Order.Select( m => m.customerID > 1).Load();
orderBindingSource.DataSource = 
   context.Order.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `Select` is just like `Where` -- it doesn't support `ToBindingList` because it returns an `IEnumerable` instead of an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: you mean "context.Order.Where( m => m.customerID > 1).Load();"?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way.
Is using load, you can see the details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/local-data
You can use Load or best loadAsync like the example

```
    dbContext.Order.Where(m=>m.customerID > 1).LoadAsync().ContinueWith(loadTask =>
        {
            // Bind data to control when loading complete
            orderBindingSource.DataSource = dbContext.Order.Local.ToBindingList();
          

        }, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: That's basically what the existing answer does. And this is not the way to handle async methods anymore.