# Convert IQueryable to BindingList

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, bindingsource

Placing `ObsevableCollection User` from DataSource as Details on new form it creates all textBoxes, BindingSource and BindingNavigator. Which is excelent and fast.

Because I only need to update one user I removed BindingNavigator. But...

Can this be without a conversion of lists?

```
class UserDt : Forms {
    // Designer partial part
    this.userBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(WinFormswithEFSample.User);

    private void UserDt_Load
    {
        _context.Users.Load();

        // use this with BindNavigator to navigate ower all users
        //this.userBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Users.Local.ToBindingList();

        // this doesn't work
        //this.userBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Users.Where(p => p.Username == "admin").Local.ToBindingList();

        var query = _context.Users.Where(p => p.Username == "admin").ToList();
        var binding = new BindingList<User>(query);
        this.usersBindingSource.DataSource = binding;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not simply convert `query.ToList()` and provide that as a parameter?

Comment: `this.userBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Users.Where(p => p.Username == "admin").ToList();` Working! Thanx @Kami. Where was my mind.

Comment: Conversion is resolved. EF question: Could it be some consequences if not using local.ToBindingList?

Comment: Finally found [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519315/entityframework4-1s-local-tobindinglist-how-to-filter-then) that uses Local.ToBindingList: `context.Order.Select( m => m.customerID > 1).Load();
orderBindingSource.DataSource = 
   context.Order.Local.ToBindingList();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can this be without a conversion of lists?

No. 
The `BindingList` takes an `IList` as an argument.
`IQueryable` cannot be casted to an `IList`, so therefor you need to *convert* it as you have already done:

```
    var query = _context.Users.Where(p => p.Username == "admin")
                              .ToList(); //converts the IQueryable to List
    var binding = new BindingList<User>(query);
```

*If* you really *need* the `BindingList` and cannot settle for a simpler `List`